# tanh transformation of symmetric positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation, covariance, positive-definite

Let a symmetric positive definite matrix $\boldsymbol{S}\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ be given.

Consider the following transformation: tanh is applied on the off-diagonal entries and the diagonal entries are set to $1$. Is the resulting matrix again positive definite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the matrix
$$ S_n=\begin{pmatrix} 4n & 2n & n \\
2n & 4n &  2n\\
n &2n &4n
\end{pmatrix} $$
Then $S_n$ is strictly positive definite as the diagonal is dominating.  The new matrix has the form
$$T_n= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & a_n & b_n \\
a_n & 1 &  a_n \\
b_n &a_n &1
\end{pmatrix} \qquad a_n={e^{2n}-e^{-2n}\over e^{2n}+e^{-2n}},\quad b_n={e^{n}-e^{-n}\over e^{n}+e^{-n}}$$
Then
$$\displaylines{\det T_n= (b_n-1)\,[2a_n^2-b_n-1)\\ =(b_n-1)[(1-b_n)-2(1-a_n)(1+a_n)]}$$
We have $b_n<1$ and
$$1-a_n\approx 2e^{-2n},\qquad 1-b_n\approx 2e^{-n}$$
Hence
$$2a_n^2-b_n-1\approx 2e^{-n} -8e^{-2n}$$
Thus $\det T_n<0$ for large $n.$

Comment: Nice answer, thanks, also works for $n=1$ I think, $S_n$ is indeed positive definite even though it is only weakly diagonal dominant

Comment: @Philipp123 Thanks. I could have taken the entries $(1,3)$ and $(3,1)$ equal $0.$ Then $b_n=0$ and $\det S_n=-(2a_n^2-1)<0$ for $a_n>2^{-1/2}.$